# Quotient of Tensor product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces and consider their tensor product $V\otimes W$. 
Now if $U\subset V\otimes W$ is a subspace of this tensor product, is there a way to relate the quotient space $(V\otimes W)/ U$ with quotient spaces of $V$ and $W$?

Comment: In other words, you're asking if we can say something like
$$
(V \otimes W)/U \cong (V/\tilde U) \otimes W
$$
is that right?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's a natural way to do what you want for arbitrary subspaces $U \subset V \otimes W$.  However, we can say something nice going in the other direction.

In particular, suppose that $X \subset V$ is a subspace. Then
$$
(V/X) \otimes W \cong (V \otimes W)/(X \otimes W ) 
$$

Comment: @levap I'll see if I can fix this

Comment: @levap I think I had the right idea the first time, and then ended up doing something bizarre because I had it in my head that $\dim(V/X) = n/x$.  In any case, now we have $(m-x)n = mn - xn$, as we should

Comment: Yeah, it looks good and it follows from the characterization of $\ker(T \otimes S)$ as $\ker(T) \otimes W + V \otimes \ker(S)$.

Comment: @levap I've never seen that, interesting.

Comment: @levap another perspective is to note that tensor products distribute over direct sums, i.e $U \otimes (V \oplus W) = (U \otimes V) \oplus (U \otimes W)$, and this equality simply takes things in the opposite direction.